# Can this be expressed in small letter?

Tags: grammar

I learned that the name of the man should be written in a capital letter.
But the name of the man is written in a small letter(prince charming).
What happened in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right; "Prince Charming" should have capitals. The cartoon's text is simply wrong. Its use of all caps for "HAGGARD" is also unnecessary. But it is a cartoon after all, so shouldn't be used as an example of proper use of language.

Comment: *Hey God!* is not idiomatic either.